# Django best practice for varying querysets dependant on user permissions and database values

Tags: python, django, view

I am new to Django and just trying to work out the best way of implementing some business logic.

I am representing access to AV devices in a building with multiple floors.  Each floor is leased by a separate tenant.  Each tenant has one or more users than can access one or more of the AV devices on the floor.  There is a tenant admin responsible for defining the users and their devices per tenancy.

I have three roles - superuser, tenant admin and tenant user.

I have a set of tables in the DB that define the floors, AV objects on the floors and which tenants can access which objects.  The admin of this in Django works fine.

I now want to display this in a simple front end so that the following is possible:

- super user - sees each floor and then can see devices on a selected floor and operate them
- tenant admin - sees just their floors and can operate all devices on their floor(s)
- tenant user - sees just the floor and devices they have been allocated access to

To my mind this can all be done in one one template with some view based logic to get the data.

Question number one is what's the best way of determining the right queryset to generate in the view?  I need to access both the user perms and then change the "WHERE" dependant on the type of user and their PK.

Question number two is how to prevent illicit access to an AV resourse.  What I don't want is someone hacking the URL or POST object to allow them to get access to an object that they are not permitted to access.  So the user must be authenticated (which is fine) and then the PKs checked to make sure the object in the DB is accessible by that user.

What's the best way of doing this?  I was tempted by just user perms but this seems the wrong way.

Hope that makes sense and TIA!